# $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1+\ln(x)}{x^2} dx$ Comparison test

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1+\ln(x)}{x^2} \,dx$$

Is this the right way to do it using comparison theorem?

For $x \in [1, \infty), f(x) = \dfrac{1+\ln(x)}{x^2} \geq 0$

For $x \in [1, \infty), f(x) = \dfrac{1+\ln(x)}{x^2} \leq \dfrac{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x}}{x^2} = \dfrac{2}{x^{3/2}} = g(x)$

Since $\int_{1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2}{x^{3/2}}\,dx$ (skipping the integration part it equals to $4$)

Therefore since $\int g(x)$ converges, then so does $\int f(x)$ by comparison test

Is this the way to do it?

Comment: It looks good..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely correct. By the way, in this case, you can prove the convergence by evaluating the integral directly
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1+\ln(x)}{x^2} \,dx=\left[-\frac{2+\ln(x)}{x}\right]_1^{\infty}=2$$
(as we expect, it  is less than your upper bound $4$).